# Sync music to frame-based time

Tags: audio, audio-video-sync

I'm making a game in which there are a series of events (which happens, say, every 30 frames in a 60fps setting) that I want to sync with the music (at 120 bpm). In usual cases, e.g. rhythm games, syncing the events to the music is easier, because human seems to perceive much smaller gaps in music than in videos. However, in my case, the game heavily depends on frame-based time, and a lot of things will break if I change the schedule of my series of events.

After a lot of experiments, it seems to me almost impossible to tweak the music without disturbing the human ear: A jump of ~1ms is noticeable, a ~10ms discrepancy between video and audio is noticeable, a 0.5% change in the pitch is noticeable. And I don't have handy tools to speed up audio without changing the pitch.

What is the easiest way out in this circumstance? Is there any reference on this subject that I can refer to? Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method I that I successfully use (in Java) is to route the playback signal through a path that allows the counting of PCM frames (audio frames run at rates like 44100 fps, as opposed to screen updates which run at rates like 60 fps). I don't know about other languages, but with Java, this can be done by outputting using a [SourceDataLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine.html) class. As the audio frame count is incremented, it can be compared to the next item (pending item) on a collection of events that require triggers to other systems or threads. Java has an excellent class for handling the collection of events: [ConcurrentSkipListSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html). It is asynchronous, and automatically sorts elements via a `Comparator` set to the desired PCM frame count.

Some example code that showing the counting of frames can be seen in this tutorial Using [Files and Format Converters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html), if you search on the page for the phrase "Here, do something useful with the audio data". They are counting bytes, not PCM frames, but the example does give the basic idea.

Why is counting PCM effective? I think this has to do with the fact that this code (in Java) is the closest we get to the point where audio data is fed to the native code controlling the sound system, and that this code employs a blocking queue. Thus, the write operations only happen when the audio system is ready to receive and playback more sound data, and audio systems have to be very accurate in how they maintain their rate of processing. The amount of time variance that occurs here (especially if the thread is given a high priority) is smaller than the time variance incurred by choices made by the JVM as it juggles multiple threads and processes.